# Stop Drupal from encoding '&' as '&amp;' in YouTube URLs

Tags: uri, theming, nodes

I embedded a YouTube video inside a "News" node. The input format in use is Full HTML.

When node is saved, the ampersand symbol in `&wmode=Opaque` is substituted for `&amp;wmode=Opaque`.

Is it possible to prevent the ampersand in the URLs of embedded YouTube videos is encoded as HTML entity?

Comment: Solved by substituting '&' for '?': http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050999/youtube-iframe-wmode-issue/4211320#4211320

Answer (score 2):

Try disabling the HTML corrector on the text format. Also, though, I don't think URL-encoding amphersands in URLs actually breaks them. & should work as a query string parameter separator as well. If not, though, see my suggestion :)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried yet but I can give you a clue. This could be a ckeditor issue or what editor may use (tinymce etc..): try to make sure you have a button like view source added to your editor button grid. Then paste the youtube link in view source mode.

Ampersands in HTML are encoded as `&amp;` That is, this is correct HTML.

If you think this won't work you need to go one step further and to display the content as plain text.

You need to edit your Full HTML input format: config/content/formats or from Configuration > Content Authoring > Text Formats > Configure and check 
Display any HTML as plain text or Convert URLs into links